# Selective mail migration Gmail > Google Apps

Tags: migration, g-suite, gmail

I've had my own small business for a while now. When I first started out I pointed my personal gmail to my business mail box and simply imported it to a label.

Currently all my company email (1 man band) is sitting under a simple label. I have several other labels which are associated with my company. My Contacts I can export and import and delete the personal ones manually.

I now want to separate my personal email and work email so have purchased google apps and am in the process of migrating.

I have come to do gmail and want to know if I can do a selective import of certain labels. into my google apps account as I have years and years worth of email in my gmail account I don't want to simply disappear. The end result should be that my business email reside in google apps and the personal stuff remain untouched in gmail. I can simply delete all the business stuff in the gmail account once I am happy it all resides in google apps.

I have no calendar entries to migrate so that's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [GAME](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration), you can set it up to migrate based on certain parameters, I believe labels may be one, have a look in the [Admin Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gapps_exchange_migration/gamme_admin.pdf) to make sure.

Comment: +1 looks promising, will go away and test if it works will accept answer. Thanks

Comment: Be aware that GAMME only lets you _exclude_ labels, rather than selecting specific labels to migrate.

Comment: Yeah its not the nicest tool, but it works. Thanks

Comment: That's about my opinion, but the fact that it works (and it's something that we do infrequently) means it's just about good enough :)